# Llamar JavaScript en un bean

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, netbeans

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente. Cuando se registre un pedido en la base de datos en la interfaz se muestre un mensaje de registro exitoso, el mensaje que debo poner es uno de `SweetAlert`.

Uso **JavaServer Faces** y quiero saber si en un método que esta en un Managed Beans tipo `SessionScoped` puedo llamar el `SweetAlert` y como lo hago?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Estos son los mensajes de SweetAlert: http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert

Comment: Hola @Lina. Con JSF puro, no se puede hacer lo que solicitas desde el backing bean. En su lugar, puedes utilizar la función `onevent` para ejecutar JavaScript antes y después de que se ejecute la acción ajax o utilizar `render` para actualizar uno o más componentes al terminar la petición ajax. Si utilizas PrimeFaces esta labor se facilita porque te provee esto fuera de la caja mediante `oncomplete`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que queres hacer no se puede. Una solución es definir alguna variable dentro del bean y colocarla dentro de un h:inputHidden, desde java una vez que el registro del pedido se realize con exito seteas esa variable con el mesaje que queres mostrar. Por ejemplo:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{Bean.variableMensaje}" id="mensaje" > </h:inputHidden>
<h:commandButton value="Registrar Pedido" id="butonRegistro">
 <f:ajax listener="#{Bean.registrarPedido()}" render="mensaje" onevent="funcion que muestre mensaje" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Y desde el metodo registrarPedido() seteas la variable "variableMensaje" con el mensaje que queres mostrar desde la interfaz.

En la funcion js obtenes el valor del inputHidden y asi va a mostrarte el mensaje que seteaste desde el bean.

Comment: En el atributo `listener` por lo general no se pone paréntesis, porque en tu backing bean, un listener tiene la forma: `public void metodo(AjaxBehaviourEvent ev)`, y si usas el paréntesis entonces jamás podrás acceder al objeto `AjaxBehaviourEvent`. Otro punto, creo recordar que `onevent` se ejecuta en las tres fases de AJAX de JSF: `begin`, `complete` y `success`, por lo que la función se ejecutaría 3 veces.

Comment: Yo he puesto metodos dentro del listener con parentesis y en el backing bean public void metodo() y me funcionó. Con respecto a lo del ajax es cierto, se ejecuta 3 veces, lo que deberia hacer es poner un if donde verifique que el status sea success.

Comment: Claro, funciona sin problemas. Me refiero a que siempre que se haga de esta forma, no se tendrá acceso al parámetro `AjaxBehaviourEvent`. A veces es útil :). Saludos.

Comment: Tal cual, tenes razón. Saludos =).

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando el atributo `onevent` de `<f:ajax />` puedes hacerlo.

```
<h:commandButton value="Registrar pedido" action="#{bean.registrarPedido()}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="mostrarMensaje(data.status) />
</h:commandButton>
```

Ahora, hay que tener cuidado con `onevent` porque por defecto se ejecutará en **las tres fases** de cada petición AJAX de JSF: `begin`, `complete` y `success`. Para asegurarse de que se muestre el mensaje solo una vez, debe hacerse en la fase `complete` o `success`.

```
function mostrarMensaje(status) {
    // luego de la petición AJAX
    if(status === 'success') {
        alert('Producto registrado');
    }
}
```